# JPA with NoSQL?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, nosql

I have been reading about JPA and Hibernate (for RDBMS), I was wondering if we can use JPA with NoSQL databases? Do we have anything like Hibernate for nosql databases?

Thanks!

Comment: what does internet search tell you? aka your research?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Data hass support for MongoDB:

http://projects.spring.io/spring-data-mongodb/

Answer (score 0):

Hibernate OGM is what you are looking for: http://hibernate.org/ogm/